# Counting duplicate rows using Excel

Tags: excel

I need to count the number of duplicate occurrences of values in a column using excel, ONLY for rows with a certain value in second column i present.

```
Column1   Column2
value1    x
value1    x
value1    x
value1    
value2    x
value2
value3    x
```

---> should give

```
VALUE  Occurencies
value1 3
value2 1
valu3  1
```

How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pivot table, which does not require any typing of values or any formulas.

Drag column1 into the row area and column2 into the values. If it is text, it will be counted. If the other values in column 2 are blank you are done. If they contain values, you can drag column2 into the filters area and then use the filter dropdown above the pivot table to select what value in column2 to use.

After you add new data to columns A and B,  select the pivot table and refresh it.

[image]

Comment: Great! Do you also know how to sort the pivot table count ascending?

Comment: Right-click into the column you want to sort and use the sort command in the context menu.

Comment: The sort option is grayed out when right clicking on the column Count of column.

Comment: Maybe you want to do a little up-skilling on pivot table? They are a great tool and can save tons of time when processing data. A few hours spent on how they work are a good investment.

Answer (score 1):

If `Column1` is in A1, please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"<>")
```

copied down to suit where D2... contain `Value1` etc